# explain a simple operation in coq

Tags: functional-programming, coq

I have the following code, 
Here `O` is the charater `O` not zero `0`

```
Module Playground1.
Inductive nat : Type :=
  | O : nat
  | S : nat → nat.

Definition pred (n : nat) : nat :=
  match n with
    | O ⇒ O
    | S n' ⇒ n'
  end.

End Playground1.

Definition minustwo (n : nat) : nat :=
  match n with
    | O ⇒ O
    | S O ⇒ O
    | S (S n') ⇒ n'
  end.

Check (S (S (S (S O)))).
Eval compute in (minustwo 4).
```

I just want to know how it evaluates to 2? I mean how it is actually checking with a numeral and subtracting? I am not subtracting anything here, still it is working? I want to know what is the basic idea here? When I call minustwo 4 how coq know it is a numeral and how it is returning the result? How the matching is working here?

Comment: BTW, the `nat`, `O`, `S`, `pred` inside the module `Playground1` are different from the ones outside the module. I think you are confused about the namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy with Coq to follow step by step what is going on. But before we can do that, we need to know what your program looks like to Coq without all the syntactic sugar. To do that, type the following in your program:

```
Set Printing All.
```

If you now print `minustwo`, you will see that

```
Print minustwo

> match n return nat with
> | O => O
> | S n0 => match n0 return nat with
>           | O => O
>           | S n' => n'
>           end
> end
```

your pattern match is actually broken up into two pattern matches.

Not let us see step by step how Coq evaluates `minustwo 4`. To do so, create the following theorem:

```
Goal (minustwo 4 = 2).
```

We don't care that much about the theorem itself, we care more about the fact that it contains the term `minustwo 4`. We can now simplify the expression step by step (you should run this in an ide to actually see what is going on).

First, we unfold the definition of `minustwo`, using a tactic called `cbv delta`.

```
cbv delta.  (* unfold the definition of minustwo *)
```

We can now call the function, using the tactic `cbv beta`.

```
cbv beta.   (* do the function call *)
```

We can now do the pattern match with

```
cbv iota; cbv beta.  (* pattern match *)
```

And because Coq broke up the match into two, we get to do it again

```
cbv iota; cbv beta.  (* pattern match *)
```

And that is why `minustwo 4` is `2`

```
reflexivity.

Qed.
```

Comment: Hi I am very new to COQ, i do not know anything about tactics. Just learning the basics.

Comment: Do you have any experience using functional programming languages? If not, I don't think Coq is the best functional programming language to start learning, there just isn't very much documentation for beginners. I would suggest to learn the basics of Haskell first. For example with this tutorial: http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters

Comment: Thank you. I am learning OCAml. And i have also figured this out.